# Keeping Object Reference when placing a Custom-Control in different WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

**Hi Experts,**

Considering MVC Pattern i created a user control (***MyUserControl1***) in this control i used windows standard controls and binding them from my data class like grid.bind, textbox.bind etc. and placing this ***MyUserControl1*** on winform (***FORM1***) it works fine but when i place ***MyUserControl1*** on another form (***FORM2***) and doing any activity over ***FORM1*** it's reflecting on ***FORM2*** automatically and vise versa. (refere snapshot )

It's seems like a control has same reference or link in both forms whereas placing ***MyUserControl1*** with different names.

its seems like MyUserControl has same reference in both form but what i want is ***MyUserControl1*** should work like standalone e.g. any change on form should not reflect to other form.

can anyone help me how to handle this please?

thanks!
[image]

### ***Relevant Code:***

***FORM 1 CODE***

```
private void COASegment4CompanyFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //placed this MyUserControl form and passing role to get role based data.*
     MyUserControl1.userRole = UserRole.Company
}
```

***FORM 2 CODE***

```
private void COASegment4MainFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //placed this MyUserControl form and passing role to get role based data.
     MyUserControl1.userRole = UserRole.Main
}
```

***MyUserControl Code:***

```
private List<MyTypeClass> MyDataList;
private void COASegment_CTL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyDataList = COASegment_BLCFactory<COASegment_CTL>.ClassFactory(this, userRole);
     // This ClassFactory class return List object using as data source. 
     // return different data based on role but all columns are same
     // e.g. userRole=Company data could be id, name, date etc, for the company and when pass userRole=Main so data would be different but same columns id, name, date etc.

     //Data Binding
     txtCode.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", MyDataList, "code"));
     txtName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", MyDataList, "name"));

}
```

Comment: The two forms can't use the same data source.

Comment: thanks for answer but i didn't get you.

Comment: I'm guessing both UserControls are binding to the same data source.  You have to show relevant code to get better help.

Comment: actually the MyUserControl1 is same but call data class based on role provided from FORM1 or FORM2 and yes object variable is same in both case so when i call this control from FORM1 so data should be according to my data class 1 or when i call FOMR2 to data should come from data class2. but what is happening whatever is last call from last form this data shows on both form.

Comment: Without showing your code, it's hard to help you.

Comment: i do prefer if you could access my machine using team-viewer so i can show you the issue and code all. or else i paste here partial or relevant code here

Comment: That's not how things work here.  You would have to post code here that duplicates the problem.  Don't post your entire project, just the relevant code.

Comment: code added please.

Comment: My guess would be that `UserRole` is returning the same DataSource since it looks like a static class.  I would start there.

Comment: datasource is changing on each userRole i checked and m quite sure about this. factory class is not static

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution, 
the datasource variable type was static